# Apps ran by console dependentment

Tags: c#, windows, bots

I'm making a windows bot in C#, part of him is running apps by for e.g. !d command it runs Discord app or !sp runs Spotify app. Whene I am doing it by cmd some of them runs fine but some like Discord and Visual Studio Code depends on console that means if I close the console the app is gonna be shutdown aswell.

```
            if (input == "!d") {
            ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
            start.FileName = @"C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Discord\app-0.0.296\Discord.exe";
            Process.Start(start);
            Run();
        }
```

This code I am using for starting the apps. Should I use something another in C# to make app independent on cmd? Or maybe it's just apps fault?

Comment: Have you tried with: `UseShellExecute =true;?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a small host application that will run the target process and wait for exit. Then your bot application can run the host and exit immediately.

Code for the host app - the first argument is the path to the target application. I'm using Windows API to hide console window:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace AppHost
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

        const int SW_HIDE = 0;

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var handle = GetConsoleWindow();
            ShowWindow(handle, SW_HIDE);

            var start = new ProcessStartInfo { FileName = args[0] };

            var process = Process.Start(start);
            process.WaitForExit();
        }
    }
}
```

Code for the bot - please note that path to the target application needs to be in double quotes:

```
var start = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = "AppHost.exe",
    Arguments = @"""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe""",
};


var process = Process.Start(start);
```